# How can I write a query to do this?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working with this database: [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ebf636).

I want to write a query to get the student name who belongs to class 2 (class_id = 2) and has the highest average, and the highest degree in a specific course(course_id = 9) at the same time, and if there is no student with these data then return nothing.

I managed to write half of it and get the student with the highest average in class 2, but I didn't know how to add the 2nd condition(highest degree in course 9), I tried in many ways it didn't work.
This is my query: (sorry for the messy code, I'm still learning)

```
SELECT s.studentname
FROM   students s
       JOIN section se
         ON s.sectionid = se.sectionid
       JOIN courses_student cs
         ON s.student_id = cs.student_id
WHERE  se.classes_id = 2
GROUP  BY s.studentname
HAVING ( Avg(cs.exam_season_one)
         + Avg(cs.exam_season_two)
         + Avg(cs.degree_season_one)
         + Avg(cs.degree_season_two) ) / 4 = (SELECT
       Max(( Avg(cs.exam_season_one)
             + Avg(cs.exam_season_two)
             + Avg(cs.degree_season_one)
             + Avg(cs.degree_season_two)
           ) / 4)
                                              FROM   students s
                                                     JOIN section se
                                                       ON s.sectionid =
                                                          se.sectionid
                                                     JOIN courses_student cs
                                                       ON s.student_id =
                                                          cs.student_id
                                              WHERE  se.classes_id = 2
                                              GROUP  BY s.studentname)
```

The way I calculate the average is:

```
( Avg(cs.exam_season_one)
         + Avg(cs.exam_season_two)
         + Avg(cs.degree_season_one)
         + Avg(cs.degree_season_two) ) / 4
```

When the way  I calculate the degree in a specific course is:

```
(cs.exam_season_one
         + cs.exam_season_two
         + cs.degree_season_one
         + cs.degree_season_two ) / 4
```

So how can I edit my query to add the second condition? or is there a better way than this?

PS: I use oracle

Comment: I just want to compliment you for giving examples and actually trying the problem yourself before posting. plus giving a link to DDL. Nicely done! I'll help in answering your question if none one else beats me to it. :-)

Comment: What if there are ties? Can the output have more than 1 record?

Comment: @Volume999 actually there will be no tie because I'm gonna insert data in a way to get only one student or no one. It sounds stupid I know but this is the assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the maximum and the average for each student and then use analytic functions to find the greatest for both conditions:

```sql
SELECT studentname
FROM   (
  SELECT studentname,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY avg_degree DESC) AS rn_avg,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY max_degree DESC) AS rn_max
  FROM   (
    SELECT MAX(s.studentname) AS studentname,
           AVG(
             cs.exam_season_one + cs.exam_season_two + cs.degree_season_one + cs.degree_season_two
           ) / 4 AS avg_degree,
           MAX(
             CASE
             WHEN cs.courses_id = 9
             THEN cs.exam_season_one + cs.exam_season_two + cs.degree_season_one + cs.degree_season_two
             END
           ) / 4 AS max_degree
    FROM   students s
           JOIN section se
             ON s.sectionid = se.sectionid
           JOIN courses_student cs
             ON s.student_id = cs.student_id
    WHERE  se.classes_id = 2
    GROUP  BY s.student_id
  )
)
WHERE  rn_avg = 1
AND    rn_max = 1;
```

*Again, don't `GROUP BY studentname` as you can have two students with the same name.*

Which outputs:

> | STUDENTNAME |
> | --- |
> | maher |

*sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ebf636/65)*

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me again! it worked.
Also thanks for the advice!